# How much can analogy between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb F_q[t]$ work out to give better distance measures in information theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, it.information-theory, big-picture

Let $x$ be transmitted symbol and $y$ be received symbol and $n$ be noise Given $y=x+n$ where symbols $x,y,n$ are in $\Bbb K$. If $\Bbb K=\Bbb Z$ then we take $|n|$ to be the magnitude of noise while if $\Bbb K=\Bbb F_q[t]$ where degree of $y,x,n$ are equal then we take Hamming weight (number of non-zero coefficients in polynomial $n$) of $n$ to be measure of noise.

Given that there is analogy between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb F_q[x]$ I have two questions:

1. Is there any natural way to think of Hamming distance to be some version of magnitude over $\Bbb Z$? (I well understand the information theoretic models and I am not going behind the probability of making errors and the fact that errors are made in discrete steps in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ model).
2. Is there any measure other than Hamming distance that may be equivalent absolute value in $\Bbb Z$ that may very well serve the purpose here?

Comment: Often the closest analogue of the absolute value in $\mathbb Z$ is the degree function $\deg \colon \mathbb F_q[t]\to \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ or its variant $f \mapsto \alpha^{-\deg f}$ for $0<\alpha<1$. For example, it is a Euclidean function on $\mathbb F_q[t]$, and it also corresponds to the 'place at infinity' that compactifies $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb F_q[t]$ (and number theorists think of the absolute value as compactifying $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$, although this is not factually true in scheme language). But that doesn't mean it's necessarily the best candidate for your purposes.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Can you explain phrase 'place at infinity' compactifying $\bf{Spec}\mbox{ }\Bbb F_q[t]$ and absolute value compactifying $\bf{Spec}\mbox{ }\Bbb Z$?

Comment: An example of this phenomenon is the definition of the [ring of adèles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring). This is a fundamental object in algebraic number theory; for example the modern proof of class field theory goes by computing the Galois cohomology of the idèles (the unit group of the adèles). This is then interpreted as some 'local-global principle' (cf. also e.g. the Hasse principle), meaning that to study $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$, it sometimes suffices to study all its completions $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Over rings like $\mathbb F_p[t]$, the analogue of this is to consider the completions at all points of the projective model $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$. This corresponds to the valuations $v_a(f)$ given by the order of vanishing of $f$ at $a$, and the valuation 'at infinity' given by the order of vanishing of $f(1/x)$ at $0$, which equals $-\deg(f)$. Therefore, $-\deg(f)$ is the thing needed to compactify $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb F_p}$, and by analogy we think of $\mathbb R$ as compactifying $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Another important result to mention here is [Ostrowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem), which classifies absolute values on $\mathbb Q$. Similarly one can classify absolute values on $\mathbb F_p(t)$, and it turns out that these are the valuations of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$, as mentioned in my previous comment.